# sign of limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Let us consider the following sequences: $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{Y_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $X_{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} a$ and $Y_{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} a$,
for some constant $a > 0$. Next, assume that
$$
\sqrt{n}(X_{n} - a) \xrightarrow{d} Z_{x}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{n}(Y_{n} - a) \xrightarrow{d} Z_{y},
$$
where $Z_{x}$ and $Z_{y}$ are some random variables.

Next, assume that $X_{n} \leq Y_{n}$ for all $n$.

Can we say something about the sign of sequence
$$
\frac{X_{n}}{n-1} - \frac{Y_{n}}{n}
$$
when $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer is generally "no". First, obviously if $X_n=Y_n$ then the sign is trivially +. We want to show that exist $X,Y$ such that the sign will be always -.

Let $a=1/2$. Let $X_n= a + \frac{1}{n}$ and $Y_n= a + \frac{2}{n}$. You can add some noise if you dont want $Z$ to be degenerate.  Then, $\frac{X_n}{n-1} - \frac{Y_n}{n} \approx \frac{a-1}{n(n-1)}<0$ for all $n>2$.